# Javascript, How do I create an array of dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make some Javascript code to find all the days up to the current date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var titleArray = [
"title1",
"title2",
];

var pictureArray = today.toString();
var thumbArray = today.toString();

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
}

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
}

today = yyyy+'_'+mm+'_'+dd;

$.each(titleArray, function(i, val) {
    $(".dailySection").append('<a href="images/daily/'+pictureArray+'.jpg" title="'+val+'"><img src="images/thumbs/'+thumbArray+'.jpg"></a>');
});
```

How to create an array of Dates in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array, then use `push()`. You should also remember that you cannot reference `today` before it is instantiated, so `pictureArray` and `thumbArray` need to get moved. Besides, unless you plan on doing something more than have each of them hold onto the same variable, I suggest getting rid of them.

Also, I believe `today` should already be a string by the time you call `toString()` on it.

```
var titleArray = [
    //a bunch of already-made and validated date strings
];

var myArray = [];

var today = new Date(); //it's a date!
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 

if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 

today = yyyy+'_'+mm+'_'+dd; //now it's a string

/* 
Unnecessary? Just use titleArray[i] 
var pictureArray = today;
var thumbArray = today;
*/

titleArray.push(today);

$.each(titleArray, function(i, val){
    $(".dailySection").append('<a href="images/daily/'+val+'.jpg" title="'+val+'"><img src="images/thumbs/'+val+'.jpg"></a>');
});
```